# Magento2 Two factor authentication for Frontend

Tags: magento2, login, security

Do you guys know where to purchase or download M2 2FA ext for FRONTEND (or both frontend and admin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Two-Factor Authentication` is a highly secure & easy to setup Two-Factor Authentication for your magento site.

- Rather than relying on a password alone, which can be phished or
  guessed, Two Factor authentication adds a second layer of security to
  your Magento accounts.
- This one protects your back-end and front-end from hacks and
  unauthorized login attempts.

---

1. https://firebearstudio.com/blog/amasty-two-factor-authentication-magento-2-extension.html
2. https://github.com/juashyam/2-Factor-Authentication

[image]

Comment: good about 2fa but both supports admin session only. Question was about Two factor authentication for Frontend.